# jQuery rotate to run infinitely

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

My question is in two parts... First one is I am using jQuery Rotate to simulate a speeded up clock. For the most part this works however it seems to stop once it reaches a certain point and I'm not sure why. The code I'm using is below and a live sample of what I am talking about is at http://www.gvh.nextcode.com.au

```
var rotation = function (){
       $("#image1").rotate({
          angle:0,
          duration: 80000,
          animateTo:360, 
          callback: rotation,
          easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
              return c*(t/d)+b;
          }
       });
    }
    rotation();
    var rotation = function (){
       $("#image2").rotate({
          angle:0,
          duration: 7500,
          animateTo:360, 
          callback: rotation,
          easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
              return c*(t/d)+b;
          }
       });
    }
    rotation();

    var rotation = function (){
       $("#image3").rotate({
          angle:0,
          duration: 80000,
          animateTo:360, 
          callback: rotation,
          easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
              return c*(t/d)+b;
          }
       });
    }
    rotation();
    var rotation = function (){
       $("#image4").rotate({
          angle:0,
          duration: 7500,
          animateTo:360, 
          callback: rotation,
          easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
              return c*(t/d)+b;
          }
       });
    }
    rotation();
```

And the second part of my question regarding the same clock, on the live sample site at http://www.gvh.nextcode.com.au you will see you can click the AM button or the PM button which essentially switches between 2 divs. This works in modern browsers however in IE8, when you select PM, the divs change correctly but no clock hands appear at all and I can't seem to work out why.

I have placed the entire javascript source relating to this area including the div switch and the clock hands themselves and I was hoping someone might be able to point me in thew right direction of what is going wrong.

```
<script>
    // set content on click
    $('.m-btns-button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setContent($(this));
    });

    // set content on load
    $('.m-btns-button.active').length && setContent($('.m-btns-button.active'));

    function setContent($el) {
        $('.m-btns-button').removeClass('active');
        $('.clock-nav').hide();

        $el.addClass('active');
        $($el.data('rel')).show();
    }

    /**Tooltips**/
    $('.clock-nav a').tooltip(); 


    var rotation = function (){
       $("#image1").rotate({
          angle:0,
          duration: 80000,
          animateTo:360, 
          callback: rotation,
          easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
              return c*(t/d)+b;
          }
       });
    }
    rotation();
    var rotation = function (){
       $("#image2").rotate({
          angle:0,
          duration: 7500,
          animateTo:360, 
          callback: rotation,
          easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
              return c*(t/d)+b;
          }
       });
    }
    rotation();

    var rotation = function (){
       $("#image3").rotate({
          angle:0,
          duration: 80000,
          animateTo:360, 
          callback: rotation,
          easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
              return c*(t/d)+b;
          }
       });
    }
    rotation();
    var rotation = function (){
       $("#image4").rotate({
          angle:0,
          duration: 7500,
          animateTo:360, 
          callback: rotation,
          easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
              return c*(t/d)+b;
          }
       });
    }
    rotation();
</script>
```

Comment: Why redefine `rotation()` over and over? Is it intended that `callback: rotation` refers to the last `function rotation()` defined?

Comment: Beside your code not working, have you considered CSS? You can rewrite that in just a few lines of CSS.

Comment: Hi all... @Roamer, thank you, I just popped back to reply to my own post with exactly what you highlighted but thank you so much for taking the time to clear that up for me... Very much appreciated.

Jonathan, thanks for replying... Yeah, CSS would be the absolute best/easiest option, unfortunately the clients entire system runs on IE8 with over 1000 employees all stuck on the dreaded browser. Otherwise, CSS would have solved all my headaches.

Comment: @mobius2000, you might want to run your current code through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com). I think it will find a couple of funnies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By redefining `roatation()` over and over, the asynchronous `callback: rotation` will in all cases call the last `roatation()` defined - ie the one associated with "#image4". The other three intended recursions will die.

You need a mechanism to ensure that each callback refers to its respective `rotation`.

You could simply change the function names to `rotation1()` `rotation2()` `rotation3()` `rotation4()` but your source will be more compact by defining a single function that can be reused x4.

Try this :

```
function rotation($image, duration) {
   //Outer function forms a closure trapping $image and duration
   //Inner function is recursive.
   var fn = function () {
       $image.rotate({
            angle: 0,
            duration: duration,
            animateTo: 360,
            callback: fn,
            easing: easing
        });
    }
}

//Easing is the same is all cases
function easing(x,t,b,c,d) {
    return c * (t / d) + b;
}

rotation($("#image1"), 80000);
rotation($("#image2"), 7500);
rotation($("#image3"), 80000);
rotation($("#image4"), 7500);
```